# Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.ts(2536)

Tags: typescript

I'm getting the above error on `result[key]` in

```js
type DataType = Record<string, number>
export function getDifference<T extends DataType>(data1: T, data2: T): T {
  const keys = Object.keys(data1)
  return keys.reduce<T>((result, key) => {
    result[key] = data1[key] - data2[key]
    return result
  }, {})
}
```

How do I get rid of it while still returning an generic type `T` so that the consuming functions still receive the correct type (instead of simply changing `T` to `DataType`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the correct type for `keys` as well as `result[key]` and `{}` manually since typescript is not able to correctly identify them automatically.

```
type DataType = Record<string, number>
export function getDifference<T extends DataType>(data1: T, data2: T): T {
  const keys: (keyof T)[] = Object.keys(data1)
  return keys.reduce<T>((result, key) => {
    if(typeof data1[key] === "number" && typeof data2[key]) { // Safeguard against object, array, etc. properties
        result[key] = data1[key] - data2[key] as T[keyof T]
    }
    return result
  }, {} as T)
}
``
```

Comment: Each property should be `number` according to `Record<string, number>`

Comment: As @AlekseyL. pointed towards, I didn't need the safeguard check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those with the similar challenge of transforming a `Record<string, string>` instead of `Record<string, number>`, you need an extra `as` on the assignment to the specific key. Here's what works:

```
function transformRecords<T extends Record<string, string>>(
  records: T
): T {
  const keys: (keyof T)[] = Object.keys(records)
  return keys.reduce(
    (results, key) => {
      results[key] = records[key] + ' lol' as T[keyof T]
      return results
    },
    {} as T
  )
}
```

You can avoid the extra `as` if you return a new object instead of mutating:

```
function transformRecords<T extends Record<string, string>>(
  records: T
): T {
  const keys: (keyof T)[] = Object.keys(records)
  return keys.reduce(
    (results, key) => ({
      ...results,
      [key]: records[key] + 'lol',
    }),
    {} as T
  )
}
```

And if you're transforming with promises:

```
async function transformRecords<T extends Record<string, string>>(
  records: T
): Promise<T> {
  const keys: (keyof T)[] = Object.keys(records)
  return await keys.reduce(
    async (results, key) => ({
      ...await results,
      [key]: records[key] + 'lol'
    }),
    Promise.resolve({} as T)
  )
}
```

Comment: The middle answer of returning a new object with the mutation also produces a much more visible output type if, for instance, you're converting a single property to another named property (AKA it produces a union type of `{ newKey: type } | Omit<T, 'Omitted'>`)